# UDP unicast over 802.11n - effect of L2 positive ACK on Linux socket send buffer

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, udp, wifi

Can anone explain how it works when an application sends UDP unicast datagrams over an 802.11 WiFi network? Assume non-blocking UDP socket. For concreteness, assume 802.11n or 802.11ac and a reasonably new Linux kernel (Android Lollipop or Debian stable). Specifically, if the sender NIC does not receive any positive ACK of send MPDUs, will the send() call return -1 and socket send queue in kernel be shown as non-empty with netstat? And the NIC will re-send same MPDUs repeatedly?

If this is not the right place to ask, please point to a good reference or another StackExchange site maybe.

Comment: A UDP send just sends. It doesn't care about success or failure. The only exception is if the socket is connected and an ICMP UNREACHABLE response has already been received to a prior send.

Comment: @EJP  But if the kernel's send buffer for that socket is full and not being emptied into the NIC ring buffers? Then a non-blocking udp socket send would return -1, right? I assume if the NIC does not manage to send anything over WiFi (e.g. because of not receiving any layer 2 positive ACK), the kernel cannot copy more data to the NIC.

Comment: A non-blocking send would return -1 with `errno` = `EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN`, and a blocking send would block. But this is a completely different question.

Comment: @EJP No, it is the same question, but maybe I did not ask the question in a clear way ;) To elaborate, we see a UDP sender app on Android over WiFi getting EWOULDBLOCK and the whole system, all 4 cores, goes idle for a long time. My best guess now is that the WiFi channel used becomes busy with other traffic (interfering access points exist on overlapping channels), and the entire Android system (shown in system trace) does nothing while waiting to be able to copy more data to the wireless NIC.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding. Wifi(layer 2) would NOT care about UDP/TCP protocol, for wifi hardware, it is just a frame,

the cast will act like this.....

frame sending ->   no ack -> retry again -> no ack -> retry -> no ack -> retry ...

after a few retry, wifi hardware will drop this frame and send next frame in NIC buffer. wifi driver should NOT always keep this frame, because frame drop or lost is frequently case in wifi.

then we talk about UDP network protocol now, because it's anon-blocking UDP socket, UDP would not care any error, it just continue sending and sending and sending....

Android phone has a feature -- "miracast", it also use UDP as a video streaming protocol and use wifi to transfer data. maybe you can check how does this function work.

Answer (score 0):

Layer-2 (Wi-Fi, in this case) knows nothing about the layer-3 protocol (IP, IPX, etc.) used, much less the layer-4 protocol (TCP, UDP, SPX, etc.) used: Wi-Fi doesn't know about IP, which doesn't know about UDP. The whole point of the network layers is that they are independent of each other. Wi-Fi can carry any layer-3 protocol, which, in turn, can carry any layer-4 protocol, which can carry any upper layer protocols.

Comment: The point is that layer 2 affects layer 4. We see EWOULDBLOCK on the udp socket, probably because packets are not dropped fast enough and socket buffer becomes full.